# Configuring second interface and assigning static IP using cobbler (kickstart file)

Tags: cobbler

I have installed cobbler on `CentOS` and I am installing new OS through pxe boot in Vcenter using cobbler server as `DHCP` and `TFTP` server. By default it will take a dhcp IP from dhcp server and configure an interface. I want to create a secondary interface and assign a static IP outside DHCP range to it.

For that I am creating an secondary interface and assigning an `IP`  keeping it in static mode using cobbler web UI.

[image]

But still it is not assigning a `static IP` for the secondary interface . Please provide a solution to assign a static IP using cobbler or kickstart file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming. You should try at https://superuser.com

Comment: Actually [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/cobbler) is more accurate for the tag Cobbler.

Answer (score 0):

The cobbler part looks ok, from what little there is there. Verify that you provisioned a second network interface in vmware for the vm.

Comment: Please turn this into an assertive answer. If you can't then please delete it, because yes, with your reputation you cannot comment and should not evade the system to do so... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead